# Can I use my own ld.so.cache?

Tags: dynamic-linking

`ldconfig` has two interesting options:

```
-f conf
      Use conf instead of /etc/ld.so.conf.
-C cache
      Use cache instead of /etc/ld.so.cache.
```

I tried copying `/etc/ld.so.conf` to my own home directory, and edited it to include paths to my local libraries e.g. `/home/syockit/local/usr/lib` etc. And ran

```
ldconfig -f /home/syockit/ld.so.conf -C /home/syockit/ld.so.cache
```

and subsequently, to confirm that the libraries are cached, I ran

```
ldconfig -f /home/syockit/ld.so.conf -C /home/syockit/ld.so.cache -p | less
```

and it does include all my libraries on top of also including system libraries.

Now, I want to have the default linker use these two. But in `man ld.so`, I see no mention of being able to use custom `.conf` or `.cache`. So what's the point of the above two options of `ldconfig` then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is no, although you can accomplish the same thing other ways.

> in man ld.so, I see no mention of being able to use custom .conf or .cache

True, but there is mention of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and and `--library-path`, the former being more generally useful.

> what's the point of the above two options of `ldconfig` then?

So you can create a cache without overwriting the system one, and without having to use the system confs.

Comment: ...just for the heck of it? Or is it for system forensics?

Comment: It could be for a system image or a chroot environment, etc.

Answer (score 7):

`/etc/ld.so.conf` is only read by `ldconfig` (the cache generation program), not by `ld.so` (the dynamic loader). You can change the location of the configuration file if you want to generate a cache that's different from the system default.

`/etc/ld.so.cache` is read by `ld.so` and you can't make it read from a different location. It can be nonetheless useful to pass a different output location to `ldconfig`. The most common use case is probably [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) environments. You can use `ldconfig -r /some/root` to run `ldconfig` on an alternate root, and put the output wherever you want (inside or outside that root). You'll need to either emit the output at `/some/root/etc/ld.so.cache` or copy it there later. There are other fairly obscure use cases, for example if you want to run `ldconfig` as an unprivileged user (who cannot write to `/etc/ld.so.cache`) and then move the file into place later.